# Cannot Write InMemoryUploadedFile to Local File in Thread - Python

Tags: python, django, multithreading

My Program is in Django. I get the uploaded files from js request.FILES:

```
my_docs = {}
for doc_title in request.FILES:
    doc_name = request.FILES[doc_title].name
    doc = request.FILES[doc_title]
    my_docs[doc_name] = doc
```

and pass them to a service object which has a 'save_docs' method:

```
class MyService():
    def __init__(my_docs):
        self.my_docs = my_docs
...
    def save_docs(self):
        for my_doc in self.my_docs:
            with open(os.path.join(self.localfile_path,my_doc),'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in self.my_docs[my_doc].chunks():
                        destination.write(chunk)
            #destination.close()

    def process(self):
    ...
        self.save_docs()
    ...
...
```

and create a thread then call it:

```
my_service = MyService(my_docs)
platform_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_service.process)
platform_thread.start()
```

However there is error:

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxxx/eclipse-workspace/My/my.py", line 97, in process
        self.save_docs()
      File "/Users/xxxx/eclipse-workspace/My/my.py", line 39, in save_docs
        for chunk in self.my_docs[my_doc].chunks():
      File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py", line 91, in chunks
        self.file.seek(0)
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The problem is when I run the program without creating a thread, it works. Why within a thread it does not? I have to use threading because I need to run several different such services at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot work with the InMemoryUploadedFile object passed into the target function. You could either save the data or pass the content of the file, although passing the file content is a bit risky as you may lose the uploaded data. Moreover, try something like celery for an async process instead of threading.